# What is the significance of the optional space in front of +- in git diff output?

Tags: git, diff

What is the significance of there being only sometimes a single space in front of a - or a + (which indicates adding or removing a line respectively)...

```
#include "devCalcWriter.h"
#include "outputDependencies.h"
#include "getVarDep.h"
 -//#include "dependencies.h"
#include "parentByRoot.h"
 +#include "find.h"
 +#include "setId.h"
+ #include "nodeCollapse.h"
#include <algorithm>
```

Answer (score 2):

You left out some crucial information: this is the output of a *combined diff*. Note that the chunk header for a combined diff has at least three `@` signs:

```
@@@ -98,20 -98,12 +98,20 @@@
```

instead of the more traditional two.

Because this combined diff is displaying the changes against two parents (vs one child merge commit snapshot), the position of each `+` or `-` will tell you which parent is being compared with the child.  Some lines may have two `-` or two `+` characters.  See [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html#_combined_diff_format) for more detail.

Git also uses combined diffs during merge conflict resolution.  Here, the two parents are the two inputs to the merge (in index staging slots 2 and 3) and the child version is whatever is in the work-tree.

Answer (score -1):

'+' when adding a new content (line)

and for:

'-' when you delete existing one.

Comment: This is true for regular diff; but the question contains a three-way diff.